# Vector in class is empty in referenced class

Tags: c++, vector, variable-assignment

I could condense my issue into the following problem:

```
Class1 x;
Class1 y;
x.Label = "Test";
y = x;
x.myVector.push_back("test");
```

Result:
`x.myVector.size()` == 1, `y.myVector.size()` == 0, yet both have the label “Test”!

I'm relatively new to C++, but unfortunately I couldn't figure the issue out by searching in the internet...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `y = x;` will copy the contents of `x` to `y`.

Comment: Let me guess, you're coming from a Java like language?  If so you should read this: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/

Comment: *I'm relatively new to C++* -- C++ works with value semantics, not reference semantics.  That line is no different than doing something like this: `int x; int y; x = 10; y = 10; x = 20;` and expecting `y` to also equal 20.

Comment: please add the code of Class1. How is the member Label defined? Do you want that y is a reference? Then try Class1& y;

Comment: So in order to avoid a copy, will I have to use a reference in a pointer variable? Because this won't work: `y = &x;` but this will `Class1* y; y = &x;`. But how can I achieve that y is not a pointer..?

Comment: @Doidel `Class1& y = x;`.  Now `y` refers to `x`.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `y = &x` -- The `&` does *not* mean "reference" in that context.  That is the `address-of` operator.  C++ is a language where simply guessing at what it is doing, or make guesses at what it's doing by using other languages as a guide, is a big mistake.

Comment: *I couldn't figure the issue out by searching in the internet...* -- This illustrates a bigger point.  Take a beginner in C++ that did not learn other languages -- they would know from (practically) day 1 that C++ works with values, and would not be baffled as to why `y` didn't change.  C++ is a language that cannot be learned by looking at other languages and making assumptions that C++ works the same way as the other languages.  You just have to learn C++ as if those other languages don't exist, i.e. from scratch, and understand the fundamentals.

Comment: in case you do know Java: In Java objects eg `Integer` have reference semantics and the primitive types eg `int` have value semantics. You could say that in C++ everything is "primitive" unless defined to behave differently (actually depending on how your `Class1` is implemented you could have either of the two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Result: x.myVector.size() == 1, y.myVector.size() == 0, yet both have the label “Test”!

Both are **supposed to have the same label because you have**:

```
x.Label = "Test";
y = x; // 'x' and 'y' are now same...
```

Which copies the instance of `x` to `y`... But this:

```
x.myVector.push_back("test"); // x is now 'test'
```

comes **after** the copy... so, it only applies to `x` not `y`... and since `vector`s are empty (so, `size()` is obviously *0*) at initialization like most of the *STL* classes...

> **Note:** *C/C++*, in code, goes forward and never looks backward, until and unless the programmer forcibly drags it back using `goto`, *loops*, or something similar...

---

**Edit:** What you might have thought would might have been for [references](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/reference), so:

```
Class1 y;
Class1& x = y;
x.Label = "Test";
// y = x; Eh, redundant statement
x.myVector.push_back("test");
```

Does what you think it should do...

Comment: "C/C++ have only one rule" unfortunately reality is a bit more complicated ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your example is far from complete, so I will just assume the simplest way for it to compile:

```
// creates an instance named x on the stack
Class1 x; 

// creates an instance named y on the stack
Class1 y; 

// sets the label of the x instance to "Test"
x.Label = "Test"; 

// COPIES all data from x over to y (including the label)
y = x; 

// inserts into the vector of x, as the copy has gone through already, this is in x only
x.myVector.push_back("test");
```

Comment: the example is also incomplete because one could define `Class1` such that the code produces just what OP expects...(whether this would be a good idea is a different question ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
Class1 x;
Class1 y;
```

Here you are making your two objects. Both have no label and an empty vector.

```
x.Label = "Test";
```

Now x has the label `"Test"`.

```
y = x;
```

Without seeing how `=` is implemented for `Class1`, it's impossible to say for sure what's happening here. If the compiler implements it, then it probably just copied everything over, so now both `y` and `x` have the label `"Test"`, and none of the vectors contain anything yet.

```
x.myVector.push_back("test");
```

Now `x.myVector` contains `"Test"`. However, this doesn't affect `y` (or `y.myVector`). That's why `y.myVector.size()` is `0`, you didn't put anything in there, so it still doesn't contain anything.